# docker traefik letsencrypt DDNS duckdns behind dd-wrt router

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, traefik, dd-wrt

I want to expose self-hosted service to access from internet (tinytinyrss, owncloud and other stuff). So I decided to use traefik as reverse proxy with letsencrypt for HTTPS certificat. Before jumping into a whole stack for each service a tried to test a simple stack with traefik and letsencrypt and a simple whoami container that respond a simple text. The docker is running on a odroid XU-4 board.

Here is my docker-compose :

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    traefik:
        container_name: traefik
        image: traefik:1.6.1-alpine
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
            - 8080:8080
        networks:
            - proxy
        environment:
            - DUCKDNS_TOKEN=my_duck_dns_token
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
            - ./traefik/acme/acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme.json
            - ./log:/var/log/traefik
        labels:
            - traefik.enable=true
            - traefik.port=8080
            - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org
        restart: always
    whoami:
        container_name: whoami
        image: hypriot/rpi-whoami
        ports:
            - 8000
        networks:
            - proxy
        labels:
            - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org;PathPrefixStrip:/whoami/
            - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https
            - traefik.docker.network=proxy
            - traefik.protocol=http
            - traefik.enable=true
            - traefik.port=8000
        restart: always

networks:
    proxy:
        name: proxy
```

And my traefik.toml :

```
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"
checkNewVersion = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[proxy]
  address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

#[traefikLog]
#  filePath = "/var/log/traefik/traefik.log"
#  format   = "json"
#  logLevel = "DEBUG"
#[accessLog]
#  filePath = "/var/log/traefik/access.log"
#  format   = "json"
#  logLevel = "DEBUG"

[docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  domain = "my_duck_dns.duckdns.org"
  exposedbydefault = false
  watch = true

[acme]
  caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
  email = "my_email_address@gmail.com"
  storage = "/etc/traefik/acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  acmeLogging = false
  [acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"
  [acme.dnsChallenge]
    provider = "duckdns"
    delayBeforeCheck = 0

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "my_duck_dns.duckdns.org"
  sans = ["my_duck_dns.duckdns.org"]
```

My router is a dd-wrt flash, I forward 80, 8080 and 443 port to a debian computer with this dock-compose on it. The router hand the dynamic duck DNS update.

I ran my containers with the folowing command :

```
docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up --build
```

And I got these logs when I try to hit the http://my_duck_dns.duckdns.org/whoami/ from the outside of my LAN. The 80 is redirected correctly to the 443 but with this log :

```
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T16:15:05Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 151.58.32.33:65175: read tcp 172.27.0.3:443->154.47.32.66:64175: read: connection reset by peer"
```

The whole DEBUG stack is below :

```
whoami     | Listening on :8000
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:55Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration file /traefik.toml"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:55Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.6.1 built on 2018-05-14_07:16:56PM"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:55Z" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#collected-data\n"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:55Z" level=debug msg="Global configuration loaded {\"LifeCycle\":{\"RequestAcceptGraceTimeout\":0,\"GraceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"GraceTimeOut\":0,\"Debug\":true,\"CheckNewVersion\":true,\"SendAnonymousUsage\":false,\"AccessLogsFile\":\"\",\"AccessLog\":null,\"TraefikLogsFile\":\"\",\"TraefikLog\":null,\"Tracing\":null,\"LogLevel\":\"DEBUG\",\"EntryPoints\":{\"http\":{\"Address\":\":80\",\"TLS\":null,\"Redirect\":{\"entryPoint\":\"https\"},\"Auth\":null,\"WhitelistSourceRange\":null,\"WhiteList\":null,\"Compress\":false,\"ProxyProtocol\":null,\"ForwardedHeaders\":{\"Insecure\":true,\"TrustedIPs\":null}},\"https\":{\"Address\":\":443\",\"TLS\":{\"MinVersion\":\"\",\"CipherSuites\":null,\"Certificates\":null,\"ClientCAFiles\":null,\"ClientCA\":{\"Files\":null,\"Optional\":false}},\"Redirect\":null,\"Auth\":null,\"WhitelistSourceRange\":null,\"WhiteList\":null,\"Compress\":false,\"ProxyProtocol\":null,\"ForwardedHeaders\":{\"Insecure\":true,\"TrustedIPs\":null}}},\"Cluster\":null,\"Constraints\":[],\"ACME\":null,\"DefaultEntryPoints\":[\"http\",\"https\"],\"ProvidersThrottleDuration\":2000000000,\"MaxIdleConnsPerHost\":200,\"IdleTimeout\":0,\"InsecureSkipVerify\":false,\"RootCAs\":null,\"Retry\":null,\"HealthCheck\":{\"Interval\":30000000000},\"RespondingTimeouts\":null,\"ForwardingTimeouts\":null,\"AllowMinWeightZero\":false,\"Web\":null,\"Docker\":{\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":2,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"Domain\":\"@.duckdns.org\",\"TLS\":null,\"ExposedByDefault\":false,\"UseBindPortIP\":false,\"SwarmMode\":false},\"File\":null,\"Marathon\":null,\"Consul\":null,\"ConsulCatalog\":null,\"Etcd\":null,\"Zookeeper\":null,\"Boltdb\":null,\"Kubernetes\":null,\"Mesos\":null,\"Eureka\":null,\"ECS\":null,\"Rancher\":null,\"DynamoDB\":null,\"ServiceFabric\":null,\"Rest\":null,\"API\":null,\"Metrics\":null,\"Ping\":null}"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:55Z" level=error msg="Failed to read new account, ACME data conversion is not available : permissions 664 for /etc/traefik/acme.json are too open, please use 600"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:55Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:0x13e3d980 Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0x13ea6c00} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:55Z" level=info msg="Preparing server https &{Address::443 TLS:0x13b82080 Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0x13ea6c10} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:55Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :443"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=info msg="Starting provider configuration.providerAggregator {}"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":2,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"Domain\":\"my_duck_dns.duckdns.org\",\"TLS\":null,\"ExposedByDefault\":false,\"UseBindPortIP\":false,\"SwarmMode\":false}"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *acme.Provider {\"Email\":\"my_email_address@gmail.com\",\"ACMELogging\":false,\"CAServer\":\"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"Storage\":\"/etc/traefik/acme.json\",\"EntryPoint\":\"https\",\"OnHostRule\":false,\"OnDemand\":false,\"DNSChallenge\":{\"Provider\":\"duckdns\",\"DelayBeforeCheck\":0},\"HTTPChallenge\":{\"EntryPoint\":\"http\"},\"Domains\":[{\"Main\":\"my_duck_dns.duckdns.org\",\"SANs\":[\"my_duck_dns.duckdns.org\"]}],\"Store\":{}}"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=error msg="Error starting provider *acme.Provider: unable to get ACME account : permissions 664 for /etc/traefik/acme.json are too open, please use 600"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 18.05.0-ce (API 1.37)"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[com.docker.compose.service:traefik org.label-schema.docker.schema-version:1.0 org.label-schema.version:v1.6.1 traefik.port:8080 com.docker.compose.oneoff:False org.label-schema.description:A modern reverse-proxy traefik.frontend.rule:Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org com.docker.compose.config-hash:d0eee974d8ebe83a1e048b7e554fad562e4c3631785fe5dc2485f947910ffb90 com.docker.compose.container-number:1 org.label-schema.url:https://traefik.io org.label-schema.vendor:Containous traefik.enable:true com.docker.compose.project:odroidtests com.docker.compose.version:1.20.0 org.label-schema.name:Traefik]"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[traefik.frontend.rule:Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org traefik.enable:true traefik.port:8080]]"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[com.docker.compose.config-hash:3586d1268056130cedb21e01704782c7d311fbcb286fd56b64e92ec8bb690e22 traefik.docker.network:proxy traefik.frontend.entryPoints:https traefik.port:8000 traefik.protocol:http traefik.frontend.rule:Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org;PathPrefixStrip:/whoami/ com.docker.compose.container-number:1 com.docker.compose.oneoff:False com.docker.compose.project:odroidtests com.docker.compose.service:whoami com.docker.compose.version:1.20.0 traefik.enable:true]"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[traefik.port:8000 traefik.protocol:http traefik.docker.network:proxy traefik.enable:true traefik.frontend.rule:Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org;PathPrefixStrip:/whoami/ traefik.frontend.entryPoints:https]]"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[com.docker.compose.service:traefik org.label-schema.docker.schema-version:1.0 org.label-schema.version:v1.6.1 traefik.port:8080 com.docker.compose.oneoff:False org.label-schema.description:A modern reverse-proxy traefik.frontend.rule:Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org com.docker.compose.config-hash:d0eee974d8ebe83a1e048b7e554fad562e4c3631785fe5dc2485f947910ffb90 com.docker.compose.container-number:1 org.label-schema.url:https://traefik.io org.label-schema.vendor:Containous traefik.enable:true com.docker.compose.project:odroidtests com.docker.compose.version:1.20.0 org.label-schema.name:Traefik]"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[traefik.port:8080 traefik.frontend.rule:Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org traefik.enable:true]]"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[com.docker.compose.project:odroidtests com.docker.compose.service:whoami com.docker.compose.version:1.20.0 traefik.enable:true traefik.frontend.rule:Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org;PathPrefixStrip:/whoami/ com.docker.compose.container-number:1 com.docker.compose.oneoff:False traefik.frontend.entryPoints:https traefik.port:8000 traefik.protocol:http com.docker.compose.config-hash:3586d1268056130cedb21e01704782c7d311fbcb286fd56b64e92ec8bb690e22 traefik.docker.network:proxy]"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[traefik.enable:true traefik.docker.network:proxy traefik.frontend.entryPoints:https traefik.port:8000 traefik.protocol:http traefik.frontend.rule:Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org;PathPrefixStrip:/whoami/]]"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Validation of load balancer method for backend backend-traefik-odroidtests failed: invalid load-balancing method ''. Using default method wrr."
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Validation of load balancer method for backend backend-whoami-odroidtests failed: invalid load-balancing method ''. Using default method wrr."
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"backends\":{\"backend-traefik-odroidtests\":{\"servers\":{\"server-traefik\":{\"url\":\"http://172.27.0.2:8080\",\"weight\":1}},\"loadBalancer\":{\"method\":\"wrr\"}},\"backend-whoami-odroidtests\":{\"servers\":{\"server-whoami\":{\"url\":\"http://172.27.0.3:8000\",\"weight\":1}},\"loadBalancer\":{\"method\":\"wrr\"}}},\"frontends\":{\"frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-0\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"http\",\"https\"],\"backend\":\"backend-traefik-odroidtests\",\"routes\":{\"route-frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-0\":{\"rule\":\"Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org\"}},\"passHostHeader\":true,\"priority\":0,\"basicAuth\":[]},\"frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-PathPrefixStrip-whoami-1\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"https\"],\"backend\":\"backend-whoami-odroidtests\",\"routes\":{\"route-frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-PathPrefixStrip-whoami-1\":{\"rule\":\"Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org;PathPrefixStrip:/whoami/\"}},\"passHostHeader\":true,\"priority\":0,\"basicAuth\":[]}}}"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating frontend frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-0"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Wiring frontend frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-0 to entryPoint http"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating route route-frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-0 Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating entry point redirect http -> https"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating backend backend-traefik-odroidtests"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer wrr"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating server server-traefik at http://172.27.0.2:8080 with weight 1"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Wiring frontend frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-0 to entryPoint https"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating route route-frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-0 Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating backend backend-traefik-odroidtests"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer wrr"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating server server-traefik at http://172.27.0.2:8080 with weight 1"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating frontend frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-PathPrefixStrip-whoami-1"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Wiring frontend frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-PathPrefixStrip-whoami-1 to entryPoint https"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating route route-frontend-Host-my_duck_dns-duckdns-org-PathPrefixStrip-whoami-1 Host:my_duck_dns.duckdns.org;PathPrefixStrip:/whoami/"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating backend backend-whoami-odroidtests"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer wrr"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating server server-whoami at http://172.27.0.3:8000 with weight 1"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:56Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :443"
traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:05Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 151.58.32.33:65175: read tcp 172.27.0.3:443->154.47.32.66:64175: read: connection reset by peer"
```

The acme.json is filled with these on the container :

```
{
  "Account": {
    "Email": "my_email_address@gmail.com",
    "Registration": {
      "body": {
        "status": "valid",
        "contact": [
          "mailto:my_email_address@gmail.com"
        ]
      },
      "uri": "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/6100073"
    },
    "PrivateKey": "MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAyg8Zb7v4cegwKpM1RxbCdrqsqfqsfdsqdfsdfgsdfgsdfg/EG0w4UP0MGD2mwZFQXAVsFjK8M3IRFP0xqNbNTQgN6nw/+pPqlxPl5kmWHIhnRp7iXGWMw/UCexT8P2eWGA9UUzXcLxwfsB74nc23nKewLBGsjRtbBXybrjtfNhLOhpPv5mF5T3s0QpT4JNlU4D3+AqnI4Vk09gVH2B+c4VK3a0Z6XsdXRPUP2oSesLyc3EeA0ayQRQyr/FAC89EDfM9BiOkONcTsCwzwQ7bstkfVXl7hZ09E0mYmdvQwMGLqTIns2EMPP3+i+/oF4SVuB/g0Sv8S06bQe54vQsHalU5EUv98ge2hfZdHLSsvgnpylTH6+TXxYIxdvqhavraxgRgirOrVV06rq5vXcHNkTW+lL/b2D23LDs/MDlJ7N5iwlycGABlNNospiYc20YLldDlY1YyZ7ToVu437+Y86gQ+msOYWlbezgE9tNbe8/kuK1zlRS8U2t4yj74YYQq96pmZTGmdnrDKnPU45JhnL6KQD1W7joLEl7UuSVvD7iVo5TpUo8VLgasKrV3WCs/FDFq1GD5S1Rbp070ZNPeA6cJaRE8cJV2fvGxQJXZUCAwEAAQKCAgB2ZsCuA8TC4p8O47INlR2guYgGVO+gAY7ZXdE1dcqD/5r6z9eRe/X4O575sNDUKu3lWDt3twkpXwKPqFSjf4DpmuJYF5Y2tSVbRlPudMESARH9UjvxJIlywYgilRV4QvArbz5anebHXzV/I/E0jmWCHVSyNe0JoYNQD0sg+kz2U9p9n8R80m+sWulQjorEmvhxIv8F3D26gM4kYOOErbFbrwdP6cdHG5g0G3qLzYfgYfQZ2I1iuN+T7TxLwdNOzMJXvW6J9GmbH+iRfFeXbmK6F1QziOfoGaVtUnwl8UA3+QyQXgXA4rlupCLqA1HoiO4h9zGG+l/ZnU9xXJJAq3VB/E38tBCBCMUB8Ms88ydsR2twq2THxRexiojCNbwxMjPV9qKi8hLU9ryl/ja7Pyu3ZgxsDNWKGla+UEdw/cw0CkmRKPIOPFmFbRiL58nSG+OLpAHpBjDkhWGH+wS/A3+snUHVPYhNzQPGwiEpunw/Yp5sbiqB4QkJAE3ThBByg3JdBsEaz0kZHyBNC3DcrqG8V4kBG0I1uMjddXfyJZd+J11RV6wPGY0hHKIdgaSvDCNIQ3A0WotnteQjG1MFWALgMaf1fxp+SQXoYVX051c6fgnCb3t+RT+CNBTnhx6tKf94DwY+TcGWdXL19Jlrp9ADPoKHOww8GbfAAkSj53F95QKCAQEA//0zCOVcwT6qoTKzD5RGcxY8XA5qy7ElMYp0cnxZt3FhMEgqzfVXmUF7JECvnRg0BhpAvW8mRbBFTvHnFuST89GAIrxH8FY4WdF+u2a82fd6fDYYGuJrWhWeMG4tl3jaj/CtdQLcfZmeP9QEPw5BGMRFHgckNrIsUGxu1CLbqDMg1kRxFdpRVrHaLQoLRoM5ClS+uskzrvXrU7yiRbH380CmIdB7wyXaS08coRmVNEFIdjNMbUw+fy5ZxotO31N2a7ACb1djKu/AhSDQbj9EwKuXD87xLO6pfHObaFe93N8zkS3UCF3CR4tnjVsAu3DZ7NFCd7tBN4y4T7CT0LRn8wKCAQEAyhFPWzGlrl4Qd9PBcxYaWo9BveiFDRqcdkaId3QI76PB7eeLgAAs6NEYH2QrqgKs46fx5f7Wqqj2PRGIImXaSAB66pzPKd+rlYYIuyKT4iYFZysRy59B3RNw2nsMF0v3WRYOOl2QA42Ziy9We1fe2E9ohPK8fUpT6ZOe5hv8rCA5iUOhDppl8dzEepPlqkEoE25DoFZR30HZGRL7JT64KK5xQtfjyyXwdFthwLj27btnUSx5ldYN8PUkALrf38YKaoiCfj3EB2jPfdul0YtmrirdvneGhpEXQDPloznmbP2/U73znfSSqZSHudI1g+x0mXB87H1J1pGkQsbPVjpOVwKCAQA0DzohxQNoCWaKAdWIhY8OOKdt0UDGy+/Uc2PbJI7aT6SEPSj3Wb3G3Ro99SnBuPpbg1tHKyONaJuvwmJMtY+hNino5oF6zw4GtiQf2HTvnvS57gZY8VMDrwHMt5tuApXwT/H2qe5NXMBiGqwCZtO2RbQIt0sWFIYOlP61BaHGQx+ac7DL0OpZxzGnlzNT07v17eYb9m8cVcbV8LbPlbHnNm6S0eNZfIk4Z45a9OjzB5PE9gnE8IyFMNfxGMOhh0e9/r2ABzWTtc5hRJse0J8az8qY3G0PxjmRpbElNzLViE7kZ32Hdgncou0cQjWT6Q9oqeXqk5pfwa56Bl8JQqchAoIBAQChl/o4WZm/ueW9jhB0MsbciRfwAVT1x8Q8KefUb2z+B5183eCHepxvi1eZMwhgK0eLv7EJVyTg0cIp0C1oJL/NOOUTXleliwOyzb+Jt/s/rVxAxwayKigH3hYwApsGvm+ORL8YGd6jmMejsTWd6gWCQu64802dfKVic/Vs3BDSreqVRQo1nW/NXdmalU/jObwM3e8i+CT9P7GYBb/mZyPrFKXq6K94tFx5EOM5tjFyqJ3VIpYRJ196xPAHzWpfkAagb4672jU8H6tfYRpYWvzAZ/Nw8DEayEkpxNbuE82cd8hb9dovBXmMOAXaqqq1V5Ffa7/bd85m043jAQ6qTHJ9AoIBAQCaz4ooInQ8eRF0umZ6NmW3j8cKNT0Avkqt2zXwgvjGTrKaud6smH8qmhS2JNAUcLSHqAGJULROWTKaJiT3UOggPEAdAC6+3pxfn3k9rIEeNU1OMTgwxNcX8JdtDw+WA+WMDk6LM/ZPZkoT6YSGcvk1V9ocp0gzFpL5prlkMbXxR6d8dcI1elTDXbHQ/zTAQiPxhjSMvwR/8HRHzEnfxU5bSQD9sKt6FZhTdi322Crjx9PmVOE6AR+kqqy9GPZ9S8oYthwLCgfuZNIuy3O1u9V5epg4vNoNEB7WDtHIxYQqfhOPHaqsfhY5t0JQBYcUoSWhFskRDvVrD1f6eZxVspcZ"
  },
  "Certificates": [
    {
      "Domain": {
        "Main": "my_duck_dns.duckdns.org",
        "SANs": null
      },
      "Certificate": "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",
      "Key": "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"
    }
  ],
  "HTTPChallenges": null
}
```

I searched everywhere on web but no one seems to get that king of issue. The trafik documentation is pretty short and well explain. Is someone can help me ? I feel that there is a little glitch but I can't put the finger on it.

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact I've already fix the access issue (chmod 600) on the acme.json certificat file. I updated the challenge and let only the DNS challenge and still get the same kind of issue.                           
traefik    | time="2018-05-21T09:18:20Z" level=debug msg="http2: server: error reading preface from client 89.3.72.155:1298: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority"

Comment: Impossible to get this thing works fine. Always an error with traefik:1.6.1-alpine image.

Comment: treafik is awesome but doesn't work for lets encrypt certificat on my side at least.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's not possible to use both challenge at the same time

   ```
     [acme.httpChallenge]
       entryPoint = "http"
     [acme.dnsChallenge]
       provider = "duckdns"
       delayBeforeCheck = 0
   ```

   When you use this configuration, in fact, only the DNS challenge is used.
2. You need to change the permissions of the `acme.json` to 600.

   ```
   traefik    | time="2018-05-18T18:30:55Z" level=error msg="Failed to read new account, ACME data conversion is not available : permissions 664 for /etc/traefik/acme.json are too open, please use 600"
   ```